# ion-searchbar enter triggers custom event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a searchbar component which works most of the time.  My html is setup

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" placeholder="Search" 
    (ionInput)=searchTermChange()>
</ion-searchbar>
```

and my component roughly looks like this:

```
@Input() settings = new SearchSettings();
@Output() search = new EventEmitter<any>();

searchTerm = '';
searchDelayTimer: any;

constructor() { }

searchTermChange() {
  clearTimeout(this.searchDelayTimer);
  this.searchDelayTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    this.search.emit(this.searchTerm);
  }, this.settings.searchDelayMS);
}
```

The component will automatically search a second or so after you finish typing.  However when I push the enter key inside of the searchbar, my searchTerm is populated with

```
{"isTrusted":true}
```

Whats even weirder is that my filter changes even though my SearchTermChange is NOT trigger.

This is how I'm consuming my filter:

```
<app-search (search)="this.config.filter=$event"></app-search>
```

Why does the search event emit when I press enter, even though I'm not triggering it?

Comment: What you mean by "when I push the enter key inside of the component"? Did you mean you press enter on search-bar?

Comment: yes when I push enter in the search bar

Comment: Try renaming your event emitter to something other than `search`. There is native `search` DOM event on `input[type=search]` that is triggered on ENTER. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/search_event